# WebGL - с чего начать?

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5, webgl

собственно сабж., Может книги какие посоветуете или статьи интересные? Только так чтоб с нуля вообще для чайников и кофеварок?

Comment: Программировать умеете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть библиотека для 2d рисования raphael.js, а для 3d - theree.js. Посмотри их.

Comment: и какое отношение Raphael имеет к WebGL

Comment: link на theree.js pls.?

Answer (score 0):

Гугль в руки и вперед

http://www.khronos.org/webgl/ - оффсайт

http://khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page - вики, пристально смотрим в графу FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Подробное руководство по webgl с азов до более сложных вещей: http://metanit.com/web/webgl/index.php