# WebGL - с чего начать ? Что почитать ?

Tags: 2d, webgl, browsers, 3d, браузер

Меня заинтересовала технология WebGL, но не знаю с чего начать её изучение.

Может ли кто-то подсказать ссылки на полезные портал или посоветовать литературу по этому вопросу, желательно с примерами, для наглядности ?

Сразу говорю, что вопрос "[WebGL - с чего начать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128481)" смотрел.
Однако надеюсь что за прошедшее время успело появиться что-то новое. Особенно интересуют тематические форумы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начните с **Three.js** некая надстройка над WebGL, позволяет 
влиться легко и безболезненно плюс куча примеров
**http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js**

Answer (score 2):

Могу еще добавить одну книгу Tony Parisi - "WebGL: Up and Running. Building 3D Graphics for the Web" и сайт: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/WebGL В книге так же есть тематические ссылки на ресурсы.